# How to get memory type?

Tags: c, windows

I was wondering if there is a way to get the installed memory type in Windows? I mean is there an API or any other way to query that on a PC there is DDR2 or DDR3 or SDRAM installed?

Thanks!

Comment: WMI query on Win32_PhysicalMemory.  Rather painful to do in C and the results are often disappointing, the WMI provider for the motherboard is often poor.

Comment: WMI COM calls in C are likely painful. Slightly better if you can use C++ for the implementation.  That, and the MSDN docs make it look way harder than it really is. Kampi, let me know if you want me to share some code on doing WMI in C++. I could dig it up. You could likely expose a "C" wrapper function to the rest of your app.

Comment: @selbie: Thanks, but there is no need for you to search a function which van make WMI calls. I already have my own :) I wanted to do it in C or C++ to avoid using WMI, because it is unreliable. But as i see i don't have any other choice :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CPU-ID](http://www.cpuid.com/) is able to do it, so it's definitely possible. They have a [SDK](http://www.cpuid-pro.com/) available, but it's [expensive](http://www.cpuid-pro.com/licenses-pricing.php).

Querying [Win32_PhysicalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using WMI may also help and is possible using [C/C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Of course it is possible. The question is how to do it? :) Win32_PhysicalMemory would be a way, however i don't like VMI, because it is unreliable. The other problem is, that this class doesn't support DDR-3 RAM

Comment: You can try tracing CPU-Z operations using ProcMon or API tracer to see how they do it.